# Compile Geany 1.26 on elementary OS Luna

Tags: gtk, development

I am running Luna (Elementary OS 0.2.1) on Ubuntu "Precise" 12.0.4. I want to compile [Geany 1.26](https://www.geany.org/Download/Releases) from the source, but when I ./configure, I get this error:

```
...
checking for GTK... no
configure: error: Package requirements (gtk+-2.0 >= 2.24 glib-2.0 >= 2.28 gio-2.0 >= 2.28 gmodule-no-export-2.0) were not met:

No package 'gtk+-2.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GTK_CFLAGS and GTK_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
```

However, I have gtk 3.0 installed, re:

```
dpkg -l libgtk* | grep -e '^i' | grep -e 'libgtk-*[0-9]'

libgtk-3-0
libgtk-3-bin
libgtk-3-common
libgtk-3-dev
libgtk2-perl
libgtk2.0-0
libgtk2.0-common
```

And:

```
pkg-config --modversion gtk+-2.0

Package gtk+-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
```

Can someone please explain the following?

1) How did this happen? Shouldn't ubuntu update the pkg-config path for me when I installed libgtk-3-0?

2) Do I really need to manually update the pkg-config search path or is there something else that should be done that will correct this problem?

I find that there are typically n+1 ways to accomplish something in linux, but sometimes the most obvious solution is not the best one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GTK+ has two major branches, 2.0 and 3.0. They are incompatible and Geany is a GTK+ 2.0 application. You'll need the development headers for GTK+ 2.0. These are included in a package called `libgtk2.0-dev`.